# Is all music Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I've always heard that music is haram, however I feel like something like this sends a positive message 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9ZFMx_mfnw
Would this and music like this be considered haram too?

Answer (score 0):

In Hadith it says Prophet Mohammad used music in his daughter wedding. (بحارالانوار: ج 43، ص 97)

In Shia Feqh it says any music that relief you and doesn't make you veryyy excited is allowed. you can refer to :

آيت‏الله مكارم، استفتاءات، ج 2، س 538 و 539 آيت‏الله صافى، جامع‏الاحكام، ج 2، س 1581 آيت‏الله تبريزى، استفتاءات، س 1051 آيت‏الله خامنه‏اى، اجوبة الاستفتاءات، س 1181 و 1180 آيت‏الله بهجت، توضيح‏المسائل، متفرقه، م 30.